# How to store large amounts of game dialogue

Tags: ios, json, text

My game is very story driven. I have lots of dialogue driven by a choice-based narrative with many different dialogue options for every character. How would I go about storing all this text?

My game uses character profile images to express the feeling of the dialogue so I need to store it in such a way that I can access it and change the emote image next to the dialogue box for each character. I may end up with upwards of 5,000 - 10,000 words in dialogue. I know text isn’t very large but I need to have a companion number (or word) with each dialogue sentence so that my dialogue class can change the character emote.

Would JSON be a good way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the texts in the localized.strings, and in the JSON return the keys to the dialogues, and in the future if you want to change any dialog or add more languages you just have to search the desired key and changed the value that it returns.

With this you will get clean JSONs and get all the texts in one file. Also, for a translator it is easier to understand.